# Is it illegal for Donald Trump to lie on his Financial Disclosures?

Tags: business, tax-law, finance

It is a very simple question, prompted by an assertion from a debate where one has claimed that he has lied on his financial disclosures, and that he is legally able to do this because:

> It is not illegal to lie on financial disclosures, because they are
>   not official documents.

The reason I specified this to Donald Trump is that I am unsure whether his position as a presidential candidate or CEO of a multi-national business changes the legality.

Comment: What disclosure are you speaking of? For some disclosures there is a prison term associating with lying, for others there is just social sanction.

Comment: @user6726 https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-stat/graphics/politics/trump-archive/docs/trump-fec-financial-disclosure-2015.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Page 1 of [OGE form 278e](https://www.oge.gov/web/oge.nsf/OGE%20Forms/48EAF45DA952AAB685257FFD006CCE93/$FILE/OGE%20Form%20278e_PDF%20ver.pdf?open) says

> **WARNINGS**
>
> Knowing and willful falsification of information, or failure to file
>   or report  information required to be reported by section 102 of the
>   Ethics in  Government Act of 1978, as amended (the Act), may subject
>   you to a  civil monetary penalty and to disciplinary action by your
>   employing  agency or other appropriate authority under section 104 of
>   the Act.   Knowing and willful falsification of information required
>   to be filed  by section 102 of the Act may also subject you to
>   criminal prosecution.

The [Office of Government Ethics](https://www2.oge.gov/Web/278eGuide.nsf/Chapters/OGE%20Form%20278e?opendocument) says that you need to fill out the form if you are running for President. Authority to require this form comes from [5 CFR 2634.201(c)](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=5:3.0.10.10.8#se5.3.2634_1201). The consequences are spelled out in [5 CFR 2634.701](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/5/2634.701). So, that one *is* an official form and there are consequences. Others might not be.

Comment: Does that mean the president of the USA is an employee?